# My CSS background image is not showing after adding <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>

Tags: css, background

**HTML**

```html
<section class="page-title">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- breadcrumb content -->
        <div class="page-breadcrumbd">
          <h2>About Us</h2>
          <p><a href="index.html">Home</a> / <a href="">Pages</a> / About</p>
        </div>
        <!-- end breadcrumb content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- end breadcrumb -->
```

**And This is My CSS**

```
.page-title{
    background: url("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/breadcrumb.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 95px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Is the problem the image is not showing or is? The question is a bit vague

Comment: Sorry it will be  " Not showing the image " !

Comment: You cannot add <?php code inside a CSS file. You can replace them with an absolute or relative URL.